# CSS child selector doesn't work on ie9

Tags: css, css-selectors

i have a page like this:

```
<body>
<table width="100%">...</table>
<table width="100%">...</table>
<table width="100%">...</table>
<table width="100%">...</table>
</body>
```

what i need to do is making all those tables 85% width and horizontally centered on the page. it would be easy if the page was a single page but this needs to work on 100+ pages and the only thing they have in common is the stylesheet file. so i need to do this with css only. i can't cover the tables inside a div or use jquery.

what i tried is:

```
body { text-align:center; }
body > table { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 85%; }
```

this works perfectly on firefox and google chrome but it doesn't seem to work on ie9 (didn't tested but i'm sure it won't work with earlier ie versions)

i've tried lots of methods they wrote on similar questions but couldn't be able to solve this.

EDIT:

The doctype of the page was:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

i changed it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and it works on ie9 too now!

The updated question is: is it possible without changing the doctype?

Comment: I'm ***sure*** the child selector itself works just fine. On the other hand, the CSS `width` rule might be ignored because of the `width` attribute on the `table` elements. Have you tried removing `width="100%"` from the markup? - it really doesn't belong there anyway.

Comment: The selector "not working" is a rather different problem from the CSS rule not being applied.

Comment: Ah, i set the doctype from "4.01 Transitional" to "1.0 Transitional" and it seems  like working now. BUT i wonder now, is there a solution that can be applied without changing the doctype (only with css as i'm trying to do) (i didn't designed this site and i don't want to edit hundreds of files)

Comment: @conrad Your HTML 4 transitional doctype doesn't look valid - see http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html

Comment: @conrad: just use the HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Not saying it will fix your issue, but it will remove malformed doctypes as an issue/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yi Jiang says, your doctype declaration isn't correct. IE9 probably can't figure out what to do about that, so runs back and hides in its quirks-mode shell, where it becomes blind to the child selector (or, becomes [10 years younger](http://ie6countdown.com)).

The easiest and surely-recommended way is to change your doctype declaration in order to get it back to standards mode and apply the rule:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Otherwise you can try forgoing the child selector and try to reset styles on the rest of your tables using whatever default styles you'd like:

```
body { text-align:center; }
body table { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 85%; }
body * table { /* Styles for other tables */ }
```

But as you see, the `*` selector there doesn't look very friendly, so changing the doctype is definitely the better path to take.

Answer (score 1):

I put together this jsfiddle and it looks like it works on IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/XFgLf/

Comment: Does the same fiddle work without using a CSS reset? Uncheck the "Normalized CSS" box. (Sorry, I can't test this myself as I'm near a Windows machine right now.)

Comment: Ah, i set the doctype from "4.01 Transitional" to "1.0 Transitional" and it seems like working now. BUT i wonder now, is there a solution that can be applied without changing the doctype (only with css as i'm trying to do) (i didn't designed this site and i don't want to edit hundreds of files)

Comment: @Matt Ball Good suggestion I tried it without the CSS reset.  I also tried it with HTML 4.01 Transitional and XHMTL 1.0 Transitional headers.  They both worked in IE9.  Conrad I thought this might help you narrow down the problem.  I don't think it's a problem with your CSS selectors given this testing.  Did you try to validate the page?  Perhaps its not valid HTML and that is causing the problem.